# Why Swagger shows previous url?

Tags: c#, web-applications, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I changed the route for my API endpoint from

```
[Route("api/v1/dataPicker/fileUploadAsync")]
```

to

```
[Route("api/v1/fileUploadAsync")]
```

But in Swagger is still shown and used the previous url. That's 
I delete Cookies at my browser, I restart Visual Studio and browser and still the is the previous url.
I searched the hole solution and "dataPicker" does not appear anywhere.

**How can I get the Swagger to use the current url?**

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What is your Swagger config and routes in Startup class?

Comment: @FIL I don't use a Swagger config file and at the startup are no routes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the good solution.
I redo the route back to [Route("api/v1/dataPicker/fileUploadAsync")] and than delete dataPicker again, I changed from kestrel to IIS and back and some when it works fine.